# Find specific item in SWT Tree

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a JFace `Treeviewer` (with underlying SWT `Tree`).
Tree contain multiple lines and multiple levels.

I want to be able to find a specific tree node (compare by text label), expand to it's level and select the item.

The main problem is that I can't loop over `TreeItems` becasue tree loads everything in LAZY mode.

Maybe there is an option to get directly to tree item by searching the model?

Comment: Do you mean you are using a tree with SWT.VIRTUAL and `ILazyTreeContentProvider`? Normally all TreeViewer operations use model objects but things are much more tricky with lazy trees.

Comment: no, i think by default the tree is lazy, it's not loading all items, only as user expands them, the children are beeing loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expand the tree to a node that may not have been shown yet you can use `TreePath` to tell the viewer about the full path to the node.
Something like:

```
List<Object> path = new ArrayList<>();

path.add(root element);

... path.add(intermediate elements in tree);

path.add(node element);  

TreePath treePath = new TreePath(path.toArray());

viewer.expandToLevel(treePath, 1);
```

The 'elements' you add to the path are your model objects as returned by the content provider.

Comment: why do I have to provide full path to my object? each object has a reference to it's 'parent', logic is implemented in ITreeContentProvider of the tree.

Comment: Quite a lot of tree content providers just return null for the parent because getParent can be hard to implement. If your getParent does work you may be able to just specify the element you want to expand rather than the path.

Comment: instead of expandToLevel will be using `setSelection(new TreeSelection(new TreePath(path.toArray())), true)` to selecte the item, and it will also expand.